# Tomorrow theme for Emacs shows Chinese charaters as blocks

Tags: emacs

I installed [Tomorrow theme](https://github.com/chriskempson/tomorrow-theme) into my Emacs24 using melpa.

Chinese characters appeared as blocks in comments while showing the correct characters in other places.

The default font in my .emacs is like following:

```
(set-default-font "Menlo-12")
(setq default-frame-alist '(font . "Menlo-12"))
```

Comment: Is it possible that Menlo doesn't support italic Chinese characters? You could try `M-x customize-face RET font-lock-comment-face`, and changing "slant" to "normal".

Comment: @legoscia Thank you so much, it's ok now. Please add an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the Menlo font doesn't support italic Chinese characters.  Type `M-x customize-face RET font-lock-comment-face` and change "slant" to "normal", and the characters should appear.